# Is it possible to create tabbed interface on a form in Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is it possible to add tabs to a Dynamics CRM 2011 form? I'm not talking about the "tabs" that are basically vertical sections on the form, which you can click the links on the navigation portion of the form to jump to.

I want a real tabbed interface like the screenshot below. Something like the jQuery tabs plugin

[image: Tabs on form]

If that is possible, is it possible to programmatically ( using javascript/xrm perhaps? ) select which tab to set to be active/show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default there is no way to do that. This tab system was retired in CRM 2011, in CRM 4 all forms had tabs like that.

The only way to do that is through Web Resources (HTML or Silverlight) but you have to add manually the controls and databinding also. Searching if exist any sample to follow i found this [article](http://madcomputerist.blogspot.pt/2011/10/adding-tabs-in-crm-2011-forms-like-crm.html) take a look.